# How to run the localhost url for post in Jax rs

Tags: java, rest, post, jax-rs

I am trying to run the localhost url for POST in jax -rs but every time I am trying to run the localhost I am not getting any results. For GET it is perfectly working.

```
@Path("playlists")

    public class PlaylistResource implements PlaylistApi {

        @Override
        @POST
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response createPlaylist(PlaylistRequest request)
    }
```

I tried:
localhost:9999/playlists/

Comment: How do you POST your request? Do you get any errors?

Comment: no i am not getting any errors the page loads without showing anything.

Comment: If you just load the page on a browser, it will make a GET request. You will need a more active client to make a POST request, and it will need to send JSON content for your method, too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want do a `post` request,you must use Postman or some other tools like that,if you only type into the address into a browser,it will be a `get` request always.

Comment: Is there any eclipse plugin with which I can get the result. Thanks

Comment: I dont use eclipse, you can try postman,it is a free software and easy to learn,if you develop complex web applications more than get request,it is a best choice